# Selecting some vector layer attributes as parameter in R script in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, rqgis

I am doing a script of R for QGIS and I need to select only some fields of one vectorial layer. I just found these option for choose several layers but not choose several attributes.

Is it possible selecting only some fields and not all of the vectorial layer?

The version of QGIS is 3.10, and I am using the plugin "Processing R provider".

Something like these...

```
##Clustering=group
##Shape=vector point
##Attributes=multiple Field       <-------
##output_plots_to_html
##showplots
##cluster=output vector
```

And that could be view these...

[image]